# Self closing application in react native

Tags: android, react-native, ibeacon, beacon

I don't know why my App is clossing by self. This is my code

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, PermissionsAndroid, Button, DeviceEventEmitter } from "react-native";
// import Constants from "expo-constants";
import Beacons from 'react-native-beacons-manager'


const requestBeaconPermission = () => {
  const region1 = {
    identifier: 'REGION1',
  };
  try {
    Beacons.detectIBeacons()
    Beacons.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region1)
    console.log(`Beacons ranging started successfully`)
  } catch {
    console.log(`Beacons ranging not started, error: `)
  }

};

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.item}>Conecting beacon</Text>
    <Button title="Conect" onPress={requestBeaconPermission} />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#ecf0f1",
    padding: 8
  },
  item: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    textAlign: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```

When try catch don't throw any error app is closing, when trow error app is still working. Maybe someone know what's bad. I'm new in react-native :D

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that onPress is being called and causing a crash before you have pressed the button.

```
onPress={() => requestBeaconPermission()}
```

I think this will show you an error as currently the logger isn't getting chance to load before your app crashes.

Edited:
From the documentation you need to call

```
Beacons.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
```

To give your app the permissions in order to access beacons if you're not already doing this (For IOS).

Also looks like others are having the same issue. Checkout the Git Issue
https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/issues/154

Comment: This is what it looks like:
1. I'm pressing on button.
2. If beacon is detected app is clossing
3  If beacon is not detected app is still runing